# Timer Job Cache Issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, visual-studio-2017

Issue Nutshell version:

Timer job WSPs seem to be cached some how.(tried commenting the whole thing out, then I deployed it, activated the feature, then restarted the service/server).

More Detail:

There is a CAML query that runs every day and pulls what is supposed to be older then 30 days to an archived area. However some of the logic was wrong and it pulled everything within the 30 days. I fixed the Query then I followed these steps:

1. Published to create the TimerJob.wsp.
2. Deployed wsp to the server.
3. Went To Central Admin > Web Applications > ?WebName? > Manage Features.
4. Activated Timer Job.
5. Reset SharePoint Timer Service (also tried restarting server).
6. Run Timer Job Manually (also waited 24 hours to see if it would run correctly on scheduled time).

With those changes the Timer Job still took the items within the 30 day period and archived them.

Background:

I think my main problem of understanding comes from having to manage an already created SharePoint Server. I don't understand how it works, or let alone how to manage it.

Comment: Hello Adam, if you are Looking for tutorial using Visual Studios 2017 to created SharePoint 2016 application, so the best thing to google it with this keyword *what's new for sharepoint 2016 developer* regarding the issue please edit your question and specify your current timer issue with more details, Thanks!

Comment: ..... those page breaks didn't work lol, new to this, ill try and fix it (Edited) Fixed it!

Comment: I discovered there are other servers at play. Perhaps restarting their SPTimerV4 is the solution, if it works ill post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timer Job was located on another server, just needed to restart that service